# Spring boot failed to run after overriding the Jackson dependencies in gradle to avoid CVE-2018-7658

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jackson, cve

Springboot 2.6.6 version application failed to start  after overiding the jackson dependencies to avoid CVE-2018-7658 by default springboot comes with jackson 2.13.2 version need to downgrade to 2.9.5 version to avoid vulnerability but application is not starting up.

Comment: Please post Exception details or complete logs for further understanding the exact issue

Comment: Try to override the last version of the `bom` instead.

Comment: Spring Boot is designed to work with a specific set of dependency versions. You can't do a massive downgrade of one of the key dependencies and expect it to work.